# building a node download module with moderate complexity

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

I'm buildinga download module for an Electron Node app, want to try `node-fetch` and have a few questions.

1. How can i get the total fileSize so i can implement a progress?
2. How can i pause/resume/cancel a download?

Also examples using other libraries **except** [request](https://github.com/request/request) or `axios` are welcome! Thanks!

This is what i have so far:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const fs = require('fs');

const url = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/45201/kitty-cat-kitten-pet-45201.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940'

async function download() {
  const nfetch = await fetch(url);

  const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream('./octocat.png');
  nfetch.body.pipe(fileStream);

  nfetch.body.on("response", (data) => {
    console.log('response ???');
  });

  nfetch.body.on("data", (chunk) => {
    console.log(chunk.length);
  });

  nfetch.body.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log('err:', err)
  });

  fileStream.on("finish", function () {
    console.log('finish');
  });
}

download();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `nfetch.headers` contains header called *Content-Length* - The image size
2. `nfetch.body` is a readable stream [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable),
   so you can use the methods: `pause()`, `resume()`, `destroy()`

Comment: Any idea how to access content-type? `console.log(nfetch.headers['content-type']);  // undefined`

Comment: It's `response.headers.get('content-type')`

Found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50060008/nodejs-parse-fetch-response-containing-object-symbolmap/50856907